# Writing to flash Attiny 85

Tags: attiny, flash

I set a project-goal for me: to make a very small compiler in Attiny.This compiler should read the code from user and translate it into code;then save it in some portion of the flash and jump there. I know this sounds impossible on Attiny85 but I want test self-programming. I read from various websites that the '85 does not have a "bootloader protection" like Atmga or Uno does. If it's true what are the functions used to write to the flash? (The only function I can thing of that access the flash is pgm_read_byte() but that is only for read).

Comment: There's an **entire** section in the datasheet devoted to this. Have you looked at it yet?

Comment: Maybe you can learn by reading and understanding an ATTiny85 bootloader, such as [Micronucleus](https://github.com/micronucleus/micronucleus).

Comment: The datasheet contains a lot of information but I could not find code for writing to Flash (it is a long datasheet and I have no ideea what to look at so maybe I missed it). @Majenko ..yes that was my next step.Thank you.

Comment: The datasheet is written from a low-level perspective. If you were working with assembly it would be useful, but when programming in C you would be better with the [AVR106 App Note](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-2575-C-Functions-for-Reading-and-Writing-to-Flash-Memory_ApplicationNote_AVR106.pdf)

Comment: You could have a look at AmForth and how it writes to flash. http://amforth.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I understand assembly(I worked in nasm).Although there are some new instructions in thendatasheet(aleo in the bootloader).I'll have to study those